# Wordpress register_activation_hook table creation not working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, activation

I've created a simple Class for my wordpress plugin. The main file looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Codes
 * Description: Generates a coupon code after checkout
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * Author: XXX
 */

require_once('inc/DatabaseUtils.php');

$codes = new Codes();

class Codes {

    private $databaseUtils;

    /**
     * Create a new instance 
     *
     * @param null
     * @return void
     */
    function __construct() {
        $this->regsiter_hooks();
        $this->databaseUtils = new DatabaseUtils();
    }

    /**
     * Called on plugin activation
     *
     * @param null
     * @return void
     */
    function activate() {
        $this->databaseUtils->setup_codes_table();
    }

    /**
     * Called on plugin deactivation
     *
     * @param null
     * @return void
     */
    function deactivate() {

    }

    /**
     * Register plugin hooks
     *
     * @param null
     * @return void
     */
    function regsiter_hooks() {
        register_activation_hook(__File__, array($this, 'activate'));
        register_deactivation_hook(__File__, array($this, 'deactivate'));
    }
}
```

In the folder ´inc´ I have a DatabaseUtils.php file. This is a class with a function to create a table in the wordpress database after activating the plugin. Here the content:

```
<?php

class DatabaseUtils {

    function setup_codes_table() {
        global $wpdb;
        global $charset_collate;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pin';
         $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
          `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `pincode` bignit(128) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)   
        )$charset_collate;";
         require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
         dbDelta( $sql );
    }

}
```

If you see, I call the function in the activation method in my main file. But when I activate the plugin there is no new table in my database.

Does anyone have a idea why? Is there a way to debug the `register_activation_hook`?

Thank's for your help!

Comment: To debug I'd do this: `$bar = dbDelta( $sql ); var_dump($bar);` that should at least get you an error message if `dbDelta` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL for creating tables in `dbDelta()` has *very* specific requirements. From [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins):

> - You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> - You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.
> - You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
> - KEY must be followed by a SINGLE SPACE then the key name then a space then open parenthesis with the field name then a closed
>     parenthesis.
> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
> - Field types must be all lowercase.
> - SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase.
> - You must specify the length of all fields that accept a length parameter. int(11), for example.

`IF NOT EXISTS` should also not be necessary when using `dbDelta()`, the purpose of which is to automatically only make changes to the database if they're necessary based on the SQL.

So your SQL should look like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pincode bigint(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)   
) $charset_collate;";
```

Your SQL lacked the 2 spaces after `PRIMARY KEY`. You also had a typo where it says `bignit` instead if `bigint` for `pincode`, and `DEFAULT NOT NULL` is not valid SQL, it should just be `NOT NULL`.

I also removed the backticks and added a space before `$charset_collate;` to be consistent with the style in the codex, but I'm not sure if they'd cause issues.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the sql. Now the plugin won't be activated :/

Comment: I just noticed I'd left the semi colon off the end of my code, if you just copied and pasted that would've broken it.

Comment: Oh yeah, i see. Now the plugin will activated but i can't find the table

Comment: Ok, I looked closer and there's other issues with your SQL. You've got a typo where it says `bignit` instead if `bigint`, and  `DEFAULT NOT NULL` is not valid SQL. Should just be `NOT NULL`. I'll update my answer to reflect these issues

Comment: No, that's not the main problem. I've changed it but no table :( .

Comment: I’ve tested the code with all those changes and it works.

Comment: I've found out that the activate method in the main file dose not run